# Problema com MDBBOOSTRAP

Tags: css, bootstrap

Bem, estou usando o hrefs abaixo e tudo fucnionava perfeitamente até ontem 07/02/2018, hoje para amanhã quando eu abri o site e cliquei em um logotipo para abrir os modelos simplesmente não abre, então parece que ele é invisível: / a questão é que, de ontem a hoje, nada foi editado em meus arquivos.

```
<link href="https://mdbootstrap.com/previews/docs/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="https://mdbootstrap.com/previews/docs/latest/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Você pode visualizar o problema acessando este link -> http://i9pixel.com/Site-Geral/

clicar no logotipo deve abrir um modelo de estilo popup. mas isso não acontece mais, o engraçado é que, se você clicar no logotipo e depois de 2 segundos, você dá 2 cliques no meio da tela, o vídeo carrega em tela cheia.

Até baixei os arquivos diretamente no site mdboostrap e colocá-lo no servidor, mudei as referências apontando para esses arquivos, mas o problema continua.

Answer (score 1):

Abrindo o console na sua aplicação, podemos ver que a mesma está exibindo a mensagem de erro : "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" ou seja, você não tem permissão para efetuar **request** para esse local.

Print tirado do console em sua página : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saiba mais sobre Same Origin Policy [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).